# sscanf format string that can detect a hyphenated and non-hyphenated string

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm working on an implementation that uses sscanf() to detect input.
Input will either contain a hyphen character '-' or it won't. The length of the strings and position of the hyphen character will vary.
Examples:

```
"18509726-550"
"14782"
```

I've been trying to come up with a format string that has a return > 0 for strings with a hyphen but not for strings without a hyphen, however I have not had success. It may not be possible. I also realize there are much better ways achieve this, but this code was written way before my time.

Code:

```
// what format string will return 0 for one but not the other?
String^ pszString = "18509726-550"; // or "14782"
int nP;
char buffer[256];
char buffer1[256];
const char* pSrc = (gcnew marshal_context())->marshal_as<const char*>(pszString);
nP=sscanf(pSrc, "%[-]s", buffer, buffer1);
```

I've tried several format strings:

```
"%s-%s"
"%[0-9-]s"
"%[-]s"
"%[^-]s"
```

I've poured over any sscanf documentation I can find, and I don't think it is possible with sscanf alone, but validation helps too.
Thanks SO community!

Comment: Sounds like you may want a regular expression.

Comment: You're right, I want a regular expression, but I'm stuck with scanf. I don't think the above is possible, but I was hoping that someone might have some better insight.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` assumes `s` format already. 
Just use `"%[^-]-%[^-]"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(const char* s)
{
    char s1[100]{}, s2[100]{};
    int n = sscanf(s, "%[^-]-%[^-]", s1, s2);
    printf("%d: %s, %s\n", n, s1, s2);
}

int main()
{
    test("18509726-550");
    test("14782");
}
```

Prints:

```
2: 18509726, 550
1: 14782,
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, that format string also returns 1 for "14782". I'm looking for a format string that recognizes "14782" does not have a hyphen and returns 0 (n=0), but at the same will return > 0 (n=2) for input like "18509726-550".

Comment: Hmm. Then just `strchr(s, '-')` no?